# read .txt file into a manipulatable string to convert into dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a .txt file with these contents:

ACC210:

Luther, Martin

Spurgeon, Charles

CS121P:

Bunyan, John

Henry, Matthew

Luther, Martin

CS132S:

Calvin, John

Knox, John

Owen, John

I need to create a dictionary so it will look like this

{'ACC210': ['Luther, Martin',  'Spurgeon, Charles']  'CS121P': ['Bunyan, John'  'Henry, Matthew'  'Luther, Martin']  'CS132S': ['Calvin, John'  'Knox, John'  'Owen, John']}

How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to make the value like that as a string or want to put it into a list / tuple, such as {'ACC210': ['Luther', 'Martin', 'Spurgeon', 'Charles']}?

Comment: yes I need multiple values per key, but the values are last name and first name together,  so {'ACC210':['Luther, Martin', 'Spurgeon, Charles']}

Answer (score 0):

This is the method of creating a dictionary...

```
# Creating an empty dictionary
myDict = {}
  
# Adding list as value
myDict["key1"] = [1, 2]
myDict["key2"] = ["Geeks", "For", "Geeks"]
```

So, for your case,

```
MyDict={}

MyDict["ACC210:"]=["Luther, Martin", "Spurgeon, Charles"]
MyDict["CS121P:"]= ... (continue)
```

Comment: How would I read the file out so I can make the dictionary?

Comment: You can read the whole file into a single string variable or you can read each line.  Python offers many ways to read it, split it, find which should be a key snd which are values. 

Google read files from Python - it is so well documented on the net, there is no reason to repeat it here. One result...  https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/